# .NET 6 web app on IIS - How to store AWS credentials

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, iis

I am creating a new app that I want to run on my local IIS. I would expect it to pull my default credentials from `%USER_PROFILE%/.aws/credentials` but whenever I try to access an AWS resource, it says that my credentials are empty.

I'm guessing the credentials in my AWS Toolkit are unavailable because the app is running outside of IIS Express. I also tried adding appsettings to my web.config (see below) but that didn't work.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="AWSProfileName" value="default" />
  <add key="AWSProfileLocation" value="%USERPROFILE%/.aws/credentials" />
</appSettings>
```

I also tried adding the `AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE`, `AWS_PROFILE`, and `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` environment variables to my site via the IIS via the Configuration Editor, but no dice.

I was able to get it to work by adding the environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, and `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` to my web.config, but I don't really want to do that (for risk of a developers credentials being put into our git repo.)

Is there something that I'm missing?

My site in IIS:

[image]

My app pool in IIS:

[image]

The permissions on the directory that contains the app:

[image]

Comment: How you store credentials is totally up to you, File, database, AWS/Azure key storage, web.config/app.settings file, Bit buckets key storage... so many ways...

Answer (score 1):

Lots options, one which worked for me in past

in `web.config`

```
<add key="AWSProfileName" value="dev" />
<add key="AWSProfilesLocation" value="D:\projects\keys\aws-api-keys.txt" />
```

or

```
<add key="AWSProfileName" value="live" />
```

and in keys file

```
[live]
aws_access_key_id=123456
aws_secret_access_key=ABCD1234
[dev]
aws_access_key_id=7654321
aws_secret_access_key=ABCFR434
```

and in code you just need to create a connection like this

```
var sqs = new AmazonSQSClient(regionEndpoint);
```

and AWS sniffs out the keys for you

see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/referencing-credentials-using-profiles/ for more info `Alternative Credentials File` at bottom of webpage